# Do I need to be worried about these SMART drive temperatures?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, temperature

I have 5 hard drives in a machine sitting in a cupboard.

`/dev/sda` is a 500GB Seagate drive, and is the boot disk.
`/dev/sd{b,c,d,e}` are 2TB drives in a `raid6` configuration.

`smartctl` is showing significantly higher temperatures (like **~140 degrees celsius**) on the raid drives than the boot drive.

**Do I need to be worried?**

`/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sde` are new Western Digital Black drives (new=1 week)
`/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` are 5 year old Hitachi drives

```
/dev/sda [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 40 to 39
/dev/sdc [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 142 to 146
/dev/sdc [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 146 to 142
/dev/sdd [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 142 to 146
/dev/sda [SAT], Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 61 to 62
/dev/sda [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 39 to 38
/dev/sde [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 107 to 108
/dev/sdb [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 108 to 109
/dev/sdc [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 146 to 150
/dev/sdc [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 146 to 150
/dev/sda [SAT], Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 62 to 61
/dev/sda [SAT], Temperature_Celsius changed from 38 to 39
```

**Update:**
Adding detailed drive information as per request:

```
/dev/sda
===========================
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Pipeline HD 5900.2
Device Model:     ST3500312CS
Serial Number:    5VV47HXA
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 02aad5ad6
Firmware Version: SC13
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5900 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 1.5 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  3 10:54:11 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

/dev/sdb
===========================
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD2003FZEX-00Z4SA0
Serial Number:    WD-WMC1F1398726
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 003b8bd25
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  3 10:54:11 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

/dev/sdc
===========================
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Deskstar 7K3000
Device Model:     Hitachi HDS723020BLA642
Serial Number:    MN1220F30WSTUD
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 369cc9f5d
Firmware Version: MN6OA580
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  3 10:54:11 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

/dev/sdd
===========================
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Deskstar 7K3000
Device Model:     Hitachi HDS723020BLA642
Serial Number:    MN1220F30WST4D
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 369cc9f48
Firmware Version: MN6OA580
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  3 10:54:11 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

/dev/sde
===========================
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-linux-3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD2003FZEX-00Z4SA0
Serial Number:    WD-WMC1F1483782
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 3002d235c
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  3 10:54:11 2014 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Answer (score 2):

If those are real temperatures, then yes, you should be worried. The Western Digital Black drives list a maximum operating temperature of [60 degrees Celsius](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701276.pdf) (PDF link). The Hitachi specification is probably similar.

However, it is extremely unlikely that the drives could reach that temperature and still run normally. It may be that the sensor is malfunctioning, or it may be reporting degrees in Fahrenheit. If so, you should consider active cooling, as the Hitachi drives are over 60 degrees.

Comment: You can easily check that by touching the drive. If you burn your finger, those are real temperatures and you should be worried. (100 °C is boiling, 150 °C is a reasonable temperature for a baking oven.) Most likely, though, those are [normalized values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) rather than raw Celsius temperatures.

Comment: I suppose it could be a normalized value, but this would be atypical for a temperature reading. The detailed drive specification would be good to have, if the OP can say what model the Hitachi drives are.

Comment: @user55325 - added drive specs

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - I can happily touch the edges of the drives - seem pretty cool to me. I've got two fans creating a lot of air flow across the drives, one on either side of the array (added when I added the WD Black drives)

Comment: You should be fine, then - based on [this](http://marc.info/?l=smartmontools-database&m=129277378418305) it looks like it's not actually reporting the raw value. Just to be sure, what is the output of `smartctl -l scttempsts /dev/sdc`?